# How do you repursue a relationship with someone who your are now best friends with?

Tags: relationships

We had been dating for a really long time (a couple years) and he very recently broke up with me and we are now best friends. I still want a romantic relationship with him and he currently does not have feelings for another.

Comment: Are you also, by any chance, user Hiltnflite? The edit seems to reflect some familiarity with the issue ...

Comment: He broke up with you for a reason. I'm assuming it wasn't done lightly. So what exactly gives you hope that he would be willing to get back together? Did you guys thoroughly discuss _why_ you broke up in the first place?

Comment: @AndreiROM Could be a different user, "he" is implied by the later text. But user8852, if you did accidentally make two accounts, you can merge them using the "contact" link at the bottom of the page :)

Comment: Can you explain your situation a little more? Without knowing more about the relationship, how/why it ended, and how things are going now, it's a little too-broad to be answered well.

Answer (score 4):

As the saying goes, "you can't go home again".

I've given this advice over the years many times.  An ex is an ex for a reason.   If he was the one doing the breaking up, he's not just going to get back together with you.

You need to move on, and probably back off from the friendship a bit, lest you lose that as well.  I've been able to be friends with most of my Exes but only after the possibility of getting back together is off the table.

See a counselor or therapist to deal with this.  You are only setting yourself up to be hurt.

Comment: People go home all the time, over and over, every day after work is over. What, do you suggest they just wander the streets?

Comment: @oMiKeY look up the saying.  You are misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 2):

What has changed?  Are the reasons for the breakup resolved?  If very little is different, then a relationship that has ended stands little chance of restarting.

It is difficult to have feelings that are not reciprocated, yet that is obviously the case here.  Movies too often make us think, "if I pursue him/her enough, he/she will love me".  That is not the case; all you will do is wind up looking desperate.

Others are saying this somewhat obliquely: it's time for you to move on.  If you can't be friends without having feelings, then it's time to put the friendship on hold.  If he really cares for you, he'll understand and support your desire for distance while you work through these feelings that he does not return.

it will not be easy.  You will miss your friend and your friendship.  I personally found it hard to stay friends with exes - I wasn't angry at them but at the same time still had romantic feelings that I knew were unproductive and caused me a great deal of pain.

Find something you love to do.  Do it with all the passion you can muster.  Maybe you will find someone who shares your passion.  If not, at least you are doing something you will love.  And over time, the pain will decrease.